# Clear notification after it is clicked

Tags: android

I want to clear my notification once it is clicked. My code is as below. Can anyone suggest where am i wrong?

public class Notification1 extends Activity
{

```
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Notification1(Context c)
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(c)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smil)
            .setContentTitle("UnHabit")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText("Continue with the set profile?");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(c, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
        c,
        0,
        resultIntent,
        0
    );
    //mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    int mNotificationId = 001;
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
            (NotificationManager) c.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :
TRY THIS**

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT))
```

Also see this link

[Android remove notification(created by mNotifyBuilder) on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032031/android-remove-notificationcreated-by-mnotifybuilder-on-click)

Comment: since i am using builder shall i add this?mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Comment: Sorry i dint post the reply. Yes 'mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;' worked properly. Thank you !

Comment: Welcome .if it helped you . you can mark it as answer so that other get Benefit from it.